# Limit Amount of Clickable Check Boxes in an Area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, checkbox, limit

I have a rails app that allows a user to create a news post. He can then tag the post with a variety of tags given to him in the form of check boxes. He can then check the check boxes that fit the post. However, i want to make sure that the user may not have over 4 check boxes checked at any given time. Is this only possible with java script? Because I the check boxes are in RoR code. Is something like a RoR check box group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It is more related to javascript .

RoR will handle just assigning the id property and onClick event to checkboxes . While creating checkboxes in RoR assign id to checkboxes in some pattern like cb1, cb2, cb3 ... . Also attach an onClick property with some javascript function which will restrict user to not able to select more than 4 checkboxes .

In javascript function count the selected checkboxes which have id like cb1, cb2 (you may use regular expression there) or also you can use a checkbox array and then iterate on it.